# GCP / Symfony : Allowed memory size of x bytes exhausted (tried to allocate x bytes) on App Engine

Tags: php, symfony, google-cloud-platform

I deployed a symfony application on GCP usign App Engine, flex environement.
I have a log message:

> WARNING: [pool app] child 13 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /app/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 171"

The memory_limt of the app is set to -1 (ini_set("memory_limit","-1")

The same thing for the container in /opt/php72/lib/php.ini

```
root@root:/app# php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
-1
```

Please help, I am really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to actual memory settings in the VM you're using.

The error is pointing you to VMs' PHP 128MB limit (134217728 / 1024 / 1024 = 128).

As you pointed out PHP is already configured to avoid limiting the resources, but in your situation the Kernel's OOMKiller will kick in.

As you're using App Engine Flexible i suggest you to increase VM's resources.

Comment: Find the solution : Just cleared the cache and it works again, but stil doesn't know what went wrong with GCP App Engine and why it's still needing clear cache after the first deployement